# 'remote write receiver' HTTP API request in Prometheus

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, prometheus, snappy, kubernetes-metrics

I am trying to find a working example of how to use the **remote write** receiver in Prometheus.

Link : https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#remote-write-receiver

I am able to send a request to the endpoint ( **POST /api/v1/write** ) and can authenticate with the server. However, I have no idea in what format I need to send the data over.

The official documentation says that the data needs to be in Protobuf format and snappy encoded. I know the libraries for them. I have a few metrics i need to send over to prometheus `http:localhost:1234/api/v1/write`.
The metrics i am trying to export are scraped from a metrics endpoint (http://127.0.0.1:9187/metrics ) and looks like this :

```
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the pause duration of garbage collection cycles.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 1.11e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 2.4039e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 3.4507e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 5.7043e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.002476999
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 0.104596342
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 1629
```

As of now, i can authenticate with my server via a POST request in Golang.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that it isn't recommended to send application data to Prometheus via remote_write protocol, since Prometheus is designed to scrape metrics from the targets specified in [Prometheus config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/). This is known as [pull model](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#pull-model), while you are trying to push metrics to Prometheus aka [push model](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#push-model).

If you need pushing application metrics to Prometheus, then the following options exist:

- Pushing metrics to [pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway). Please read [when to use the pushgateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/) before using it.
- Pushing metrics to [statsd_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_exporter).
- Pushing application metrics to VictoriaMetrics (this is an alternative Prometheus-like monitoring system) via any [supported text-based data ingestion protocol](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-import-time-series-data):

  - Prometheus text exposition format
  - Graphite
  - Influx line protocol
  - OpenTSDB
  - DataDog
  - JSON
  - CSV

  All these protocols are much easier to implement and debug comparing to Prometheus remote_write protocol, since these protocols are text-based, while Prometheus remote_write protocol is a binary protocol (basically, it is [snappy](https://github.com/google/snappy)-compressed [protobuf messages](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tree/main/prompb) sent over HTTP).